# How do you remove indentation from a single element in an array - perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

```
@para_text[2] = $mech->xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]', type => $mech->xpathResult('STRING_TYPE'));
```

I have the above code which returns the following in this format:

```
                                    Sent:


                                    30 March 2017 11:59
```

I need it to be in this format:

Sent: 30 March 2017 11:59

They are indents and not just spaces, i have tried grep, trim and various substitution methods suggested in other forums and threads to no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines can be used to truncate all whitespaces from a multiline string. I would rather sugest putting these lines in to function.

```
@para_text[2] =~ s/[\r\n]//gm; # convert multiline to single line
@para_text[2] =~ s/\s*$//;   # remove trailing whitespaces
@para_text[2] =~ s/^\s*//;   # remove preceding whitespaces
@para_text[2] =~ s/\s+/ /;   # merge tabs
```

Comment: That removes the whitespace before sent however anything after sent still has the whitespace